# Git multiple sub projects from sub folders?

Tags: git, github

I have multiple projects that I'd like to put up onto GitHub.com.  All of these projects are in my local Git repository.  I have just one repository, but for each project, I'd like to have 1 GitHub project.  That way, bugs can be organized by the project.

How can I set this up so that it isn't that difficult to manage?  Do I need to redo my repository layout and create new git repositories locally for each project?  That would be really time involved and I might be losing the Git history.

Walter

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Depending on how your repo is organized, you can use `git filter-branch` to create a new repo for each project, retaining history for each individual project *only*.

Assuming your current repo structure is like this:

```
repo/
  project1/
    project1-file
  project2/
    project2-file
  project3/
    project3-file
```

You can first *clone* your repo (`git filter-branch` *will* remove files *and* their history, so clone your original repo *first*). Then, in your cloned repo, you can use `git filter-branch` to create a new repo (with all the old history) at the root of `project1`:

```
$ git filter-branch --subdirectory-filter project1 HEAD
```

Now, your repo will look like the following:

```
repo/
  project1-file
```

And it will still contain the history for all files that were stored under `project1/` in the old repo.

Repeat that step for each project, and you will now have three independent repos, with all the history for their relevant projects.

Comment: Thanks, that looks like exactly what I want.

Answer (score 5):

If I'm understanding the question, you've got one large repo that contains a number of projects. You would like to break each of those projects out into individual repos without losing history. Bottom line is yes, you have to redo your repository layout and create new git repositories for each project. You don't need to lose history, though.

1. Make a copy of your current repo, one copy for each sub project.
2. In each of the new repos, delete all other projects except for the one associated with that repo.

You'll still have all the history prior to breaking the original repo up, but now each project is it's own repository.

If you don't mind losing your history, making each project into it's own git repo is as simple as running `git init` in the project directory. This will create a new repo for just that project.

Comment: That makes sense.  I think what I'll do is do the latter, git init for each project.  When I am ready to publish that to github, I want to have a relatively clean codebase ...