# Git Sub Projects

Tags: git, github

I know this has been answered many times, but I'm new to git and I'm being especially dense, so I could use some detailed help.

I have a website where the main directory talks about my programming experience (obviously it's a pretty short page, since I'm new to git). It has multiple subdirectories, each of which is a pitch page and description of a project I've done. I'm trying to figure out how best to organize this and push it to github. [This solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3246480/git-multiple-sub-projects-from-sub-folders) looks like what I want to do, but I just can't seem to get my head around how to do it.

My directory structure looks like this:

```
www/apps/
  apps-files
  spark/
    spark-files
  minder/
    minder-files
```

I want each project page to have its own README.md, and want to be able to send hyperlinks to each project page's github page. If it makes a difference, I will also have separate repos for each of the projects that these sites describe.

I have already created most of one of the pages, but have not created a git repo or committed anything yet.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In case anyone else was having issues with this, I'll give you an easy step-by-step of what I did:

In Github, I created new remote repositories for apps/, spark/ and minder/.

In www/apps/spark/ I did:

1. `git init`
2. `git add --all`
3. `git commit -m "initial commit"`
4. `git add remote origin <github web address for spark repo>`
5. `git push -u origin master`

Then I `cd`'d to www/apps/minder and did all that again, using the minder repo. I verified that everything was hosted on github properly, and then in www/apps I used `rm -rf spark && rm -rf minder` to delete both folders completely. Next I did the same five steps above in the root www/apps folder with the apps repo.

Finally, in www/apps I ran the following

1. `git submodule add <github web address for spark repo> spark`
2. `git submodule add <github web address for minder repo> minder`
3. `git submodule init`
4. `git submodule update`

This left me, on my local system, the folder layout listed in the question. To make changes to spark or minder I just make sure I make the pushes from their folders, and when I push apps I need to remember to push with the submodules if needed. The drawback to this approach is that minder and spark are hosted twice in my github account, both as separate repos and inside apps, but I don't have an issue with that.

### Bonus Round!

I also created a dev folder so I could have test and production code hosted on the same system. That worked like this:

1. For all three repos, I added a 'dev' branch from the Github webpage
2. Create dev/ folder at same level as apps/
3. `cd dev`
4. `git clone <github web address for apps repo> apps`
5. `cd apps`
6. `git submodule init`
7. `git submodule update`
8. `git checkout dev`
9. `cd minder`
10. `git checkout dev`
11. `cd www/test/apps/spark`
12. `git checkout dev`

Now I have two parallel folder trees (and consequently two parallel websites, since this is on a home server), and in the test folders all my pushes go to the dev branch:

```
www/apps/
  apps-files
  spark/
    spark-files
  minder/
    minder-files
www/test/
  apps/
    apps-dev-files
    spark/
      spark-dev-files
    minder/
      minder-dev-files
```